# How i can define eager loading for my repository method in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

i have the following action method that calls a repository method:-

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        { 
            Instructor i = repository.FindInstructor(i);
            ViewBag.assessmentid = repository.FindassessmentID(id);
            if (i == null)
                return View("NotFound");
            else
                return View(i);}
```

but how i can define that i need to define an eager loading for the `Position` navigation property on the instructor entity (as the instructor might hold 0 or many positions), the `FindInstructor(i)` repository method look as the folloiwng:

```
public Question FindInstructor(int id)
        {
           return entities1.Instructors.FirstOrDefault(d => d.InstructorID == id); }
```

the intellisense will **NOT** allow me to write something like :-

```
return entities1.Instructors.Include(c => c.Position).FirstOrDefault(d => d.InstructorID == id); }
```

so what i am missing in my code???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overload of the [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method which takes a property expression is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace.

Add this using to your file and it should work:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

You can read more about how eager loading works: [Loading Related Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply, i update the repository metohd to the folloiwng "return entities1.Questions.Include(c => c.Answers).FirstOrDefault(d => d.QuestionID == id);". so will i get the eager loading working fine ? or there still some modifications i should do ? BR

Comment: Yes EF will do eager loading with the `Include`. So it will issue one SQL query to get the Question and all the associated Answers.

Comment: so it will retrive the Position navigation property after applying the d => d.InstructorID == id and not before? ,, i mean it will not retrive the Position navigation property for all the the instructor objects and then select the intended Instructor object ??

Comment: It will only retrieve the Positions for the Instructor = id. It will generate a SQL query like this: `select * from Instructor i left join Position p on i.Id = p.InstructorId where i.Id = @id`. You can check the executed queries with the SQL server profiler.